# Infinite Caroussel Loop onClick using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble building a carrousel using jQuery: I am currently adding and removing classes using next() or prev() but I would like to loop infinitely trough all the slides as I click. Here's a perfect example of what I would like to do: [mfglabs.com](http://mfglabs.com).

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container-slider">
        <ul>
            <li class="slide current">
                <article>
                 // My content
                </article>
            </li>
            <li class="slide">
                <article>
                // My content
                </article>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".next").click(function () {
        $(".slide").removeClass("current");
        $(".slide").next().addClass("current");   
    });
    $(".prev").click(function () {
        $(".slide").removeClass("current");
        $(".slide").prev().addClass("current");   
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '`slide`' class is generic in all items. You can apply common CSS styles using that, but can't select one particular item by this '`slide`' class. You need to select element by something unique. in this case- its '`current`' class.

This can be a good approach-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".next").click(function () {
            if($(".current").next().length){
                // if Next element Exists
                var nextElem = $(".current").next();
                $(".current").removeClass("current");
                nextElem.addClass("current");   
            }else{
                // No Next item i.e. reached Last item
                // Selecting first item to make it 'current'
                var firstElem = $(".current").parent().children().first();
                $(".current").removeClass("current");
                firstElem..addClass("current");   
            }
        });
        $(".prev").click(function () {
            // something similar
        });
    });
```

Comment: Works great thank you. Actually I had made it work with something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/zstNj/ but your solution is actually better! Thank you.